# How can I watch DVR device video stream on Raspberry via Ethernet?

Tags: raspbian

Normally I can watch DVR device camera streams on a Windows PC using [iDVR-E Series Surveillance DVR Remote Access Enterprise Management Software](https://www.cctvcamerapros.com/DVR-Remote-Access-Enterprise-Management-Software-s/492.htm).

However, I want to use TV to watch my camera streams instead of the Windows PC. How can I watch it by Raspberry Pi. Is there any software for Raspbian, or any advice?

Comment: Have you tried entering the URL you posted in Chromium?

Answer (score 0):

To watch a DVR device's video stream on a Raspberry Pi via Ethernet, you'll need to follow these general steps:

Connect the Raspberry Pi and the DVR device to the same local network.
Make sure both devices have a valid IP address on the same subnet.

Determine the IP address of the DVR device.
You can usually find this information in the DVR's network settings or documentation.

Install VLC media player on your Raspberry Pi.
VLC is a versatile media player that can handle various video formats and streaming protocols.
Open a terminal on your Raspberry Pi and run the following command to install VLC:

sql
Copy code
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
Launch the VLC media player on the Raspberry Pi.
You can typically find it in the "Sound & Video" or "Multimedia" sections of your desktop environment's applications menu.

In the VLC menu, click on "Media" and then select "Open Network Stream" (or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+N).

In the "Network" tab of the "Open Media" window, enter the network address of the DVR device.
This will typically be in the form of an RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol) or HTTP stream URL.
The specific URL format will depend on the DVR manufacturer and model.
For example, an RTSP stream URL might look like this:

arduino
Copy code
rtsp://192.168.1.100:554/stream
Replace "192.168.1.100" with the actual IP address of your DVR device and adjust the port number and stream path if necessary.

Click "Play" to start the video stream.
If everything is set up correctly, VLC should connect to the DVR device and begin playing the video stream.

Note: The steps above provide a general guideline, but the specific process may vary depending on the DVR device and its streaming capabilities.

Answer (score -3):

omxplayer is the answer, you can stream multiple cameras in a grid pattern.

https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Video/Tutorial-RTSP-Raspberry-Pi-B-Viewer-6-Cam-4-Cam/td-p/1536448

Comment: lol a down vote already.... did you read the linked article... I doubt it.

Comment: This system will be used by security staff and they are not security expert. So I need yo GUI manage cameras.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.